# How do I select an XML schema registered with Oracle?

Tags: oracle, xsd

How do I select an XML schema previously registered with Oracle?

For example, if I've registered a schema like so:

```
DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.registerSchema(
    SCHEMAURL => 'http://test.com/my-schema.xsd',
    SCHEMADOC => '...the xsd...,
    ...
);
```

I would like to be able to get that schema back,
ideally something in the vein of:

```
select s.schemadoc
from magic_schema_table s
where s.schemaurl = 'http://test.com/my-schema.xsd'
```

Does such a mechanism exist?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Datadictionary View ALL_XML_SCHEMAS.

```
SELECT SCHEMA
FROM   ALL_XML_SCHEMAS
WHERE  SCHEMA_URL = 'http://test.com/my-schema.xsd';
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this schema is altered - it is "enriched" with oracle extensions, e.g. oraxdb:propNumber="4558" oraxdb:global="false".

Answer (score 0):

I found an workaround here: [Remove all annotations added into schema by Oracle dbms_xmlschema.registerschema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57120355/remove-all-annotations-added-into-schema-by-oracle-dbms-xmlschema-registerschema).

```
Select regexp_replace(s.schema.getClobVal()
                     ,'( oraxdb:.*?= *".*?"| 
                     xmlns:oraxdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb")','')
from user_xml_schemas s
where s.schema_url = 'my schema XDB URL';
```

Answer (score -2):

You should find your answer there : [XML Schema Storage and Query: Basic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb05sto.htm#BJFDCFII)

**Update:**

The only other thing that I can see which can help you would be to generate a schema for a given object type. Here is the way to go: [Generating XML Schemas with DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.GENERATESCHEMA](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb06stt.htm#i1032141)

Comment: This link appears to be about retrieving schema annotations, not the original xsd itself.